# How to perform automatic parameter assignment according to the pattern of filename?

Tags: bash, directory, filenames, parameter, patterns

Suppose there are two type of csv files with the following filename format:

```
Ass_B1_v1_<ShortName>_<ddmmyyyy>.CSV
CATUpd_v1_<ShortName>_<ddmmyyyy>.CSV
```

Or the format can be changed to:

```
Ass_B1_v1_<ShortName>_<Name>_<ddmmyyyy>.CSV
CATUpd_v1_<ShortName>_<Name>_<ddmmyyyy>.CSV
```

The `<ShortName>` are the short form of `Name`:

```
Name|ShortName
A1 Dun|A1
Ant Cap|AC
.
.
.
```

I have a list consisting `Part_Name` & `Target_Directory` which
`Part_Name=echo ${Name} | sed -e 's/ /_/'`
`Target_dir=D:\GFTPRoot\Receive\${Part_Name}\LIST\ASCII\OUT`

List.txt:

```
Part_Name|Target_Directory
A1_Dun|D:\GFTPRoot\Receive\A1_Dun\LIST\ASCII\OUT
Ant_Cap|D:\GFTPRoot\Receive\Ant_Cap\LIST\ASCII\OUT
Bri_Deb|D:\GFTPRoot\Receive\Bri_Deb\LIST\ASCII\OUT
.
.
.
```

I normally hard-code this & assigned the parameter by reading the parameter from the list
(For example, List.txt)

```
[ ${ShortName} = "A1" ] && {
part=`grep ^"$A1_Dun" ${List} | cut -d"|" -f1`
Target_dir=`grep ^"$A1_Dun" ${List} | cut -d"|" -f2`}

[ ${ShortName} = "AC" ] && {
part=`grep "$Ant_Cap" ${List} | cut -d"|" -f1`
Target_dir=`grep "$Ant_Cap" ${List} | cut -d"|" -f2`}

.
.
.

for file in `find ${path} -name "*${ShortName}*" -type f`
do
.
.
```

The list is quite long. Instead of hard-coding, I wish to search all the csv files with the pattern `*$ShortName*`, then assigned `$Part_Name` & `$Target_dir` to the `$ShortName`.

For example, for all the csv files with the particular pattern `*$ShortName*`,
assign the parameter `Part_Name` & `Target_dir` for each sub-set of files with the particular pattern.

Comment: Something is amiss in this query. For example, where is the mapping from `shortname -> name` ?

Comment: Also there is no way to search for file with the `pattern *${ShortName}*` This can only be done once we grab the CSV files and then extract whether they comprise the short name in them or not.